# Python - measure amount of memory used in script

Tags: python, memory, profiling

I have a Python script and I would like to measure the amount of memory that it uses. I have tried `memory_profiler` but I could not find the right option for me.

I would like something that I can use as:

```
results = {}
for i in range(10):
    l = [1]*i*1000
    memory = compute_used_memory()
    results[i] = memory
```

in order to know the amount of memory used during different phases of the program.

**EDIT:**
I do not have much experience but I'll try to explain the problem better. I need to deploy my code on a machine where I will have access only to a limited amount of memory (such as 1 GB). As a consequence I need to know how much memory my code will use.  As the code will run incrementally with increasing complexity I need to make sure that the amount of memory used converges to a maximum value. For this reason I need to measure how the amount of memory used changes at different stage of the execution that is in this case represented by a for loop
.

Comment: This is kind of a tricky question, and there are a few ways you could interpret it in terms of allocated to utilized memory. Do you want total allocated memory of the program? Do you want a percentage of used to allocated memory? Do you want total memory allocated at a particular point in the program? A little more clarification may help.

Answer (score 9):

Hmm, if you are using python3.4 and later you can use the tracemalloc module

```
import tracemalloc
tracemalloc.start()
profiled_code_here
print("Current: %d, Peak %d" % tracemalloc.get_traced_memory())
```

Answer (score -1):

Im guessing Python3 so try with the "Resource" module. The getrusage function should give you what you need.

[Start here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html#resource-usage)

example EDIT:

```
import resource
for i in range(10):
    l = [1] * i * 1000
    memory = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF)
    print(memory.ru_utime)
```

The function returns an object with various properties which you can access (check the docs for every one of them).

Comment: I actually need for python 2 but something for python 3 is a good start

Comment: then here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html#resource-usage

Comment: cna you please write an example usage?

Comment: Editing answer just a sec

Comment: Which one is the total amount of used memory among the values that it returns?

Comment: From http://pythonforbiologists.com/index.php/measuring-memory-usage-in-python/ this seems to be the correct usage `resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss`